# Read in values for variables from sample.dat files when redirected to stdin?

Tags: python, stdin

I want to read some values in 4 input files containing variables called xc , yc, r, x1, y1, etc.... The input file are formatted such as they look like:

```
400, 300200100, 200700, 200
```

I was told this can be made with the eval() command, such as:

```
xc, yc = eval(input())
```

can you show me how this works ?

Answer (score 0):

Your original question is quite unclear... I proposed to rewrite it but I'm not sure I understood the question. Meanwhile it is hard to use the eval() command, since I didn't understood the format of the input files. I would rather consider:

```
import numpy as np
filenames = ["toto.dat","tata.dat","tutu.dat","titi.dat","tyty.dat"]
for count,file in enumerate(filenames):
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        inp = np.array(f.readlines())
    if count==1:
        xc = inp
    elif count==2:
        yc = inp
    elif count==3:
        x1 = inp
    elif count==4:
        y1 = inp
    else:
        x2 = inp
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, however when i try to import numpy like in your code, apparently it can't find numpy as a module. So it just gets an error in the first line of the file.

Comment: install numpy. if you're using anaconda ==> conda install numpy. otherwise with pip: pip install numpy (to be verified, I never use pip). otherwise any installer